# problema con Ubuntu 18.04 sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu

Buenas tardes amigos les cuento que soy nuevo usando Ubuntu, y pues en clase pidieron que usaramos Ubuntu para aprender a programar, y en mis aventuras por instalar codeblock y este no me dejaba empecé a buscar varios tutoriales y nada en lugar de instalarlo lo arruine todo, ahora no puedo usar los comando de actualización y me da muchos errores [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisá el contenido de tu archivo 'source.list', seguro tenés errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Perdón pero como lo hago, espero no ser molesto, pero encerio no se nada

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

intenta hacer esto desde terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Y ya estando adentro muévete hasta la linea 45 y comenta la con un #.

`# Comentario`

Guarda con `Ctrl + O` y para salir utilizas `Ctrl + X`.
Luego solo vuelve a intentar hacer:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Amigo ya hice lo que me indicas, pero me dice que solo lee 2 líneas y me sale así.   Línea 1. Vacia.... Línea 2. Sudo apt-get update

Comment: En ese casi olvida lo del comentario, elimina la linea 45 y me dices que tal.